# VSTO Excel: Detect Last row of ListObject Deleted

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

So I'm working on a VSTO Excel application and need to detect when a ListObject has been deleted by the user.

e.g. given a table like this in Excel

[image]

and some code like this

```
this.listObject.Change += (s,e) =>
{
   Debug.Print("Changed!);
};
```

The ListObject.Change event is not fired when the last row is removed!

Is there a way to detect ListObject last row deleted, or ListObject itself deleted from a Worksheet?

Answer (score 2):

Just to make it clear: are you deleting whole spreadsheet row or just a table row? From the screenshot it seems that you have whole row selected. Try to only select one row of the table (not additional empty cells besides the table row) and then Right Click -> Delete -> Delete Rows. Does this trigger your event?

You could also catch the Change event on the Worksheet and check if the row contained any of the ListObject data.

Comment: Hello, ListObject.Change is not raised if you select just the table rows and select delete. I did find a workaround though, if I subscribe to Worksheet.SelectionChanged (only event that consistently fires) and check for ListObject.DataBodyRange = null then I know that the body of the table has been deleted. Similarly ListObject.HeaderBodyRange = null detects if the entire table has been deleted. Thanks for your help!